# Не могу перенаправить вывод в утилиту createuser. Postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, unix

Нужно скриптом создать postgres юзера с паролем. Делаю через утилиту createuser под юзером postgres :

```
echo -e "PASSWORD\nPASSWORD\n" | createuser -P
```

в результате получаю запрос на ввод пароля:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чо делать, как жить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
psql -c "CREATE ROLE ignat WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '123456'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать expect. Что-то типа:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn createuser -P
expect "Enter password for new role:"
#below enter password
send "password"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

> Чо делать, как жить?

Я в постгрессе не работал, но по аналогии, можно было бы попытаться это сделать в два шага в скрипте с параметрами "имя" и "пароль":

1. Создаём пользователя без пароля

   createuser $1
2. Изменяем таблицу пользователей, задавая пароль только что созданному пользователю:

   echo "ALTER USER $1 PASSWORD $2\nQUIT\n" | psql

Это я очень приблизительно написал, что бы идею только показать.